# Windows Batch Script: list all files with name, path, size and owner into a csv file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script which can list all files under a folder and its subforlders, with some properties such as path, file name, modified date and size. But, I can't add one extra property, file owner.

```
@ECHO off
SET v1=%%~dpF
SET v2=%%~nxF
SET v3=%%~zF
(for /r %%F in (*) do @echo "%v1%","%v2%",%v3%) > test.csv
PAUSE
```

Basically I want to add a 4th parameter, which should show file owner. It is in Windows 7 environment.

Comment: Also, why have you set `%v1` to `%%dpF` etc, instead of just using `%%dpF` inside the for loop?

Comment: Because I will have many more lines, it is better to have variables, where I can change them, and it will effect the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dir` command with the `/q` switch to include the owner of each file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%a in (*) do for /f "tokens=5" %%b in ('dir /q "%%~fxa" ^| findstr "%%~nxa"') do (
    echo "%%~dpa","%%~nxa","%%~za","%%b"
) >> test.csv
```

This will always append to `test.csv`, if you want to always recreate `test.csv` you can encase your entire for loop in parenthesis (as you had);

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /r %%a in (*) do for /f "tokens=5" %%b in ('dir /q "%%~fxa" ^| findstr "%%~nxa"') do (
    echo "%%~dpa","%%~nxa","%%~za","%%b"
)) > test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but I adapted a PowerScript to show what you ask for. Just update the PARAM section with your file and folder names, copy and paste into PowerShell and hit enter twice:

```
PARAM (
  $Path = 'C:\Users\PATHHERE\',
  $report = 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\OUTPUTFILENAMEHERE.csv'
)
$LastWrite = @{
  Name = 'Last Write Time'
  Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('u') }
}
$Owner = @{
  Name = 'File Owner'
  Expression = { (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner }
}
$HostName = @{
  Name = 'Host Name'
  Expression = { $env:COMPUTERNAME }
}

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Path | 
              select $HostName, $Owner, Name, Directory, $LastWrite, Length   | 
              Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $Report
```

This script adapted from info [found here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b57db5e3-f610-45ba-ac17-89df72b14cfa/inserting-file-owner-into-a-getchilditem-listing). I find batch files to be more and more trouble to deal with these days, and PowerShell is very flexible. The guys over at [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com) will no doubt be able to help you better with these kinds of questions.