# Windows Batch : list all files with name, path, data modified, date created and owner into a csv file or txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that can display the file path, there are some properties that can not be displayed, such as date modified, date create, owner.

```
@ECHO off
SET v1=%%~dpF
SET v2=%%~nxF
(for /r %%F in (*) do @echo "%v1%","%v2%"
pause


Example Output :
- D:/newfolder1/tester.doc | 18/02/2016 01:30:00 | 16/02/2016 02:13:12 | Nickolas
- D:/newfolder2/tester2.doc | 11/03/2016 01:30:00 | 12/02/2016 02:13:12 | Marx Timberlack
- D:/newfolder3/tester3.doc | 18/02/2016 01:30:00 | 16/02/2016 02:13:12 | Administrators
```

Basically I want to add a 4th parameter, which should show file owner. It is in Windows 7 environment.

Comment: You might be able to use the `icacls` command and parse the output; or use PowerShell and its `Get-Acl` command.

Comment: Since you seem to have copied the question in part [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414694/windows-batch-script-list-all-files-with-name-path-size-and-owner-into-a-csv) why didn't you work through the answers there and provide some own code? [SO] isn't a code writing service, don't expect others to put more effort in your task than you yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by Klitos Kyriacou, PowerShell can do this:

```ps1
PARAM (
    $Path = 'C:\Users\MarxHood\Desktop\', $Report = 'C:\Users\MarxHood\Output.csv'
)

$Owner = @{
    Name = 'FileOwner'
    Expression = { ((Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner).Split('\')[1] }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Select FullName, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, $Owner | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|" $Report
```

Just change the locations as necessary for `$Path` and `$Report` at the top.

**Edit**

Below is a method using a batch file, unfortunately this is dependent upon the localised date/time output; *(tokens may need adjusting to suit your locale)*. Domain names in the owner output string which contain a space would also cause this to fail.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "Path=C:\Users\MarxHood\Desktop"
Set "Report=C:\Users\MarxHood\Output.csv"

(For /F "EOL= Tokens=1,2,4*" %%A In ('Dir/A-D/-C/Q/TC "%Path%\*"'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%E In ("%%~tD"
) Do Echo="%%~fD"^|"%%E"^|"%%A %%B"^|"%%~nC")>"%Report%"
```

Remember to change the locations as necessary for `%Path%` and `%Report%` near the top.

Comment: Waht about `$Path = "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Desktop\",   $Report = "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Desktop\Output.csv"`?

Comment: Whilst it's not a bad idea to use environment variables, it seems a pointless addition as the OP doesn't specify any locations, just a drive letter. It was easier for me just to list easily editable paths in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `dir /TC` will show you the creation date of each file.  `/TA` will show you last-access, and `/TW` will show last-written.

Comment: My impression is that both created and modified are required though and I'm doubtful that `Dir` can do that in one pass.

Comment: Not in a single pass, it would require multiple passes.

Comment: Try reading the documentation.  `dir /?`  The answer is clearly document.